# How to implement inheritance using composer autoloader?

Tags: php, oop, composer-php, autoloader

I have 2 classes that each of them has 2 methods. Also I have some constant data between all methods of all classes.

So I used of a Father class containing those constant data and then I extended other classes of Father class *(for accessing constant data in all methods of all classes)*.

Here is my structure: [github demo](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b78a52c2dfb4f5ee4c5d)

```
// c:\xampp\htdocs\myweb\classes

// ---------------------------------------------------- Father.php
  class Father{
    protected $arr1 = array("there is some data in here");
    protected $arr2 = array("there is some data in here");
    protected $arr3 = array("there is some data in here");
  }


// ---------------------------------------------------- Autoloader.php
  function my_autoloader($class) {
      require_once($class.".php");
  }
  spl_autoload_register('my_autoloader');


// ---------------------------------------------------- Child1.php
  class Child1 extends Father{
    public function func1(){// using of those array in this method}
    public function func2(){// using of those array in this method}
  }



// ---------------------------------------------------- Child2.php
  class Child2 extends Father{
    public function func1(){// using of those array in this method}
    public function func2(){// using of those array in this method}
  }
```

Now I want to know, how can I implement my code using composer autoloader?

Comment: You want the documentation of [psr-0/4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/)?

Comment: @Federico I want to use composer.

Comment: I don't understand, you want use composer's autoloader? Or what?

Comment: @Federico yes I want to use composer's autoloader

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real question is : 'How do I use composer?'

https://www.codementor.io/php/tutorial/composer-install-php-dependency-manager

So when you've ran through that, with consideration of your current project in your question:

- You'd take your autoloader out, because that will all be handled by the file that composer will generate for you. In fact, if you have all your php files currently in the same directory, so you dont need your autoloader currently.
- You'd `include` the composer autoloader that is generated in a bootstrap file, a file which is loaded on every page run in your project.
- You'd give every class its own file, like you have done here. This is part of adhering to `psr`. You'd setup some namespacing with adherance to `psr-4`.
- If you have an old legacy project, were there is no possible hope of renaming every class to do comply with `psr`, you would generate the classmap entirely, which would work for multiple classes in one file. However, using the `psr` naming standard is optimal from the beginning in most cases.